# Find the number of rectangles not containing the shaded square

Tags: rectangles, multigrid

I wish to find the number of rectangles that don't contain the shaded square:

Image of the grid:
[image: This is the grid]

I used the way of finding the total number of rectangles and subtracting the rectangles containing the square. I can't calculate the latter.

I'd be grateful if someone helped me.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I used the way of finding the total number of rectangles and subtracting the rectangles containing the square. I can't calculate the latter

Comment: Are the rectangles required to have grid points as their vertices?  Assuming so, are the rectangles required to have their sides parallel to the sides of the large rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label the vertical lines in the grid from left to right, starting from $1$ upto $9$. Similarly label the horizontal lines from top to bottom, from $1$ to $6$.

Now, the black square is formed by intersection of the $5^{th}$ and $6^{th}$ vertical lines with the $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ horizontal lines.

If the rectangle chosen should not contain the black square, the 2  vertical lines for making a rectangle should be chosen either from  the set of vertical lines labelled {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$} OR {$6, 7, 8, 9$}. Hence the total number of options for choosing the vertical lines is $\binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{2}$.

Similarly, for horizontal lines, we have $\binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{2}$.

Hence, the total number of options is :

$[\binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{2}][\binom{3}{2} + \binom{3}{2}]$